# dataRow.ItemArrray to CSV with one column as datetime

Tags: vb.net, csv, datetime

I have a datatable with fields like ID, Date1, Amount etc

i want to convert data rows to CSV format

ie: -

```
101 | 2017-10-10 | 15000
102 | 2017-10-15 | 12500
103 | 2017-10-25 | 20000
```

I am using below code to convert rows to CSV string:

```
Dim rowAsString = String.Join(", ", dRow.ItemArray.Select(Function(c) "'" & c.ToString() & "'").ToArray())
```

and output is: -

```
101, 10/10/2017 12:00 AM, 15000
102, 15/10/2017 12:00 AM, 12500
103, 25/10/2017 12:00 AM, 20000
```

what i want is: -

```
101, 2017-10-10, 15000
102, 2017-10-15, 12500
103, 2017-10-25, 20000
```

please help me with above linq query to format date value field in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Try following :         Dim rowAsString = String.Join(", ", dRow.ItemArray.Select(Function(c, i) IIf(i = 1, "'" & c.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'", "'" & c.ToString() & "'").ToArray()))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this `DataRow` extension:

```
public static string ToCsvString(this DataRow row, string delimiter)
{
    return ToCsvString(row, delimiter, null, null);
}

public static string ToCsvString(this DataRow row, string delimiter, string dateFormat, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
    if(dateFormat == null)
        dateFormat = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.ShortDatePattern;
    if (formatProvider == null)
        formatProvider = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;

    var fields = row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select(c => c.DataType != typeof(DateTime)
            ? row[c].ToString()
            : row.Field<DateTime>(c).ToString(dateFormat, formatProvider));
    return string.Join(delimiter, fields);
}
```

Usage:

```
string rowAsString = dRow.ToCsvString(", ");
```

VB.NET version:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
Public Function ToCsvString(row As DataRow, delimiter As String, dateFormat As String, formatProvider As IFormatProvider) As String
    If dateFormat Is Nothing Then
        dateFormat = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.ShortDatePattern
    End If
    If formatProvider Is Nothing Then
        formatProvider = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo
    End If

    Dim fields = row.Table.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().
        Select(Function(c) If(c.DataType <> GetType(DateTime), row(c).ToString(), row.Field(Of DateTime)(c).ToString(dateFormat, formatProvider)))
    Return String.Join(delimiter, fields) ' with .NET 3.5 you need fields.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your code. it is giving following error: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Data.DataColumn,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'  can you please convert it to vb.net code. may be i generated wrong code while converting it to vb.net

Comment: @GLSOFTINDIA: then you are using .NET 3.5, use `return string.Join(delimiter, fields.ToArray());` because `String.Join` only accepts arrays for you

Comment: i am already using this code in .net 3.5. Is there a way out to convert date field value other than loop ?

Comment: @GLSOFTINDIA: i dont understand your question. You wanzt to convert every field in your DataRow to string. Of course you need some kind of loop. I'm using the LINQ "loop".

Comment: Yes, string is ok for every other column except date column with gives me output in 25/10/2017 12:00 AM format. Rather I need this value in 2017-10-25 format

Comment: @GLSOFTINDIA: what doesn't work with my code? It does what you want and i have even added a VB.NET version. I have mentioned .NET 3.5 because you can use `String.Join(delimiter, fields)` only with .NET 4 and newer. With your version you need `String.Join(delimiter, fields.ToArray())`

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are right. it working properly with fileds.ToArray() in .Net 3.5.  Good re-usable code with the help of extension method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. `i = 1` should be changed to the date column.

```
Dim str As String = String.Join( _
    Environment.NewLine, _
    dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().Select( _
    Function(r) String.Join( _
        ",", _
        r.ItemArray().Select(Function(o, i) If(i = 1, Format(o, "yyyy-MM-dd"), o.ToString())).ToArray() _
        ) _
    ).ToArray() _
)
Console.WriteLine(str)
```